# Modeling favorites in Django from two different models

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I have a Netflix clone app that I am creating and I am having difficulty with the models.
I have a Movie model that has fields for the movie such as a title, duration, rating, etc.
I am not sure how I should model my database but what I believe I should be doing is a ManyToMany relationship, such as, a user can favorite many movies and a movie can be favorited by many users.

However, if I do it like this I feel that I would end up with a Favorites table that would have many users and movies and possible see this as an issue having to go through each row to find the current user rather than doing maybe a OneToMany relationship, such as, a user can favorite many movies and a movie can be favorited by a user.

So first, I am not sure what the proper way of modeling this would be.

I also do not know how to add this relationship to my user model because I am using the User model that I brought in from `django.contrib.auth.models`

I am having a lot of trouble trying to think of a solution for this and I don't want to just add a many to many field for users to the movie table that I have without understanding if and why it is a good/bad approach.

Comment: You can work with a `GenericForeignKey`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly but wouldn't this mean that I would want a GenericRelation instead. According to the docs it seems like I would not be able to filter for all the user favorites with the GenericForeignKey but with GenericRelation I would be able to do `.all()` to get all the favorited movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class User(...):

    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    ....

class Movie(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Favorite(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='favorites', ...)
    movie = models.ForeignKey('Movie', related_name='favorites', ...)
```

Then we can do:

```
# a particular user's favorite movies:
user = User.objects.get(id='the_user_id')
user.favorites.values('movie')

# number of users who have favorited a particular movie:
movie = Movie.objects.get(id='the_movie_id')
movie.favorites.count()
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out before accepting it, but this does look like what I wanted. Do you know if there is a difference between just adding a many to many field of users to the movie model itself?

Comment: Django will automatically create the 'Favorites' table if you set a ManyToMany field on the users model (or movies model) so your db schema will essentially be identical. There are actually many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. Best idea is to try out something simple and expand your code as your needs grow.